# Cannot enable my network adapter - Failed to start Raise network interfaces

Tags: networking, 20.04

I need some assistance. I was following some instructions (https://thedarksource.com/how-to-solve-this-adb-server-version-doesnt-match-this-client-error-in-android/) to configure Android Studio so I could use my cellphone instead of the emulator. I'm not sure what I did, but after rebooting, I got this *'No Wifi adapter found'* message in Settings. The wifi icon is gone.
I tried to re-enable the adapter (wlp1s0), but I couldn't. Apparently the adapter works OK, but it is DOWN, and I can't turn it on.
I looked everywhere for an answer. Googled it. Tried every command (ifconfig,iwconfig, ip nmcli, nmtui, lshw, lspci...) Restarted the service. Reinstalled the driver. Update. Full-upgrade... Kind of lost here.

```
dante@inferno:~$ ifconfig -a
bnep0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.44.204  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.44.255
        inet6 fe80::60c4:ff4a:cfe:9541  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:d4:0c:c1:6f:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2462  bytes 1404234 (1.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2907  bytes 312851 (312.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 220249  bytes 17721776 (17.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 220249  bytes 17721776 (17.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 08:d4:0c:c1:6f:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0:avahi: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.5.241  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        ether 08:d4:0c:c1:6f:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

```
dante@inferno:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:d4:0c:c1:6f:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.5.241/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link wlp1s0:avahi
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: bnep0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:d4:0c:c1:6f:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.44.204/24 brd 192.168.44.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute bnep0
       valid_lft 2732sec preferred_lft 2732sec
    inet6 fe80::60c4:ff4a:cfe:9541/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
dante@inferno:~$ sudo lspci -v
{...}
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at d1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 08-d4-0c-ff-ff-c1-6f-01
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
```

```
dante@inferno:~$ nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         60:A4:D0:3F:35:CF
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         60:A4:D0:3F:35:CF
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Galaxy J7 Prime Network
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveC>
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.44.204/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.44.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.44.1, mt >
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.44.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt>
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.44.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::60c4:ff4a:cfe:9541/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 750

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ::1/128, nh = ::, mt = 256

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:D4:0C:C1:6F:01
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         169.254.5.241/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            0.0.0.0
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt >
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1002
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

```
dante@inferno:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 79
       serial: 08:d4:0c:c1:6f:01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-53-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 7265D-29.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:127 memory:d1000000-d1001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: 08:d4:0c:c1:6f:05
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.204 multicast=yes
```

I modified this file

```
dante@inferno:~$ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces
#auto br0
#
#iface wlp1s0 inet manual
#
#iface br0 inet dhcp
#    bridge_ports wlp1s0

auto wlp1s0

iface wlp1s0 inet dhcp
```

Edit: Here's the Bash history. It stopped working after the reboot.

```
cd platform-tools/
adb devices
sudo apt install adb
adb devices
adb kill-server
which adb
rm /usr/bin/adb
sudo rm /usr/bin/adb
sudo adb kill-server
ps ax | grep adb
adb devices
cd opt
cd /opt
ls
sudo apt install adb
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt uninstall adb
sudo apt remove adb
sudo apt install adb
adb devices
reboot
sudo reboot
```

UPDATE:

Found this .conf file in /etc/modprobe.d/. Could this be the issue?

```
dante@inferno:/etc/modprobe.d$ sudo cat iwlwifi.conf 
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Running `nmcli connection show` gives this:

```
dante@inferno:/etc/modprobe.d$ nmcli connection show 
NAME                     UUID                                  TYPE       DEVICE            
Galaxy J7 Prime Network  5708e684-0c82-4575-934a-eafc7d085d1c  bluetooth  60:A4:D0:3F:35:CF 
Rubik                    a4558960-102c-4db7-b0de-6a0ee5b73e4d  wifi       --                
virbr0                   e4aaa4c1-b37f-4bae-942b-da4680fb4411  bridge     --
```

My WiFi connection (Rubik) is shown, but I can't connect.

UPDATE:

I get this message at boot:

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2021-05-17 18:08:38 -03; 12s ago
       Docs: man:interfaces(5)
    Process: 3607 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 3607 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

may 17 18:08:15 inferno ifup[3632]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x36f5b28)
may 17 18:08:33 inferno dhclient[3632]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x36f5b28)
may 17 18:08:33 inferno ifup[3632]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x36f5b28)
may 17 18:08:38 inferno systemd[1]: networking.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
may 17 18:08:38 inferno ifup[3607]: Got signal Terminated, terminating...
may 17 18:08:38 inferno ifup[3607]: ifup: failed to bring up wlp1s0
may 17 18:08:38 inferno systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
may 17 18:08:38 inferno systemd[1]: networking.service: Killing process 3635 (dhclient) with signal SIGKILL.
may 17 18:08:38 inferno systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
may 17 18:08:38 inferno systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

```
dante@inferno:/etc/network$ sudo ifdown wlp1s0 && sudo ifup wlp1s0
ifdown: interface wlp1s0 not configured
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlp1s0/08:d4:0c:c1:6f:01
Sending on   LPF/wlp1s0/08:d4:0c:c1:6f:01
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x58283243)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x58283243)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

The problem is related to a bridge (br0... I erased it) and DHCP, but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Thank you @user535733. The release is in the Tags. It-s 20.04.

Comment: These are the instructions I was following: https://thedarksource.com/how-to-solve-this-adb-server-version-doesnt-match-this-client-error-in-android/

Comment: Well, I tried everything... every command: ifconfig, ip, iwconfig, nmcli, lshw, lspci, netplan... turn on and off... restarting services, reinstalling the driver, updating and upgrading the system. Name it, chances are I already tried that. I don't know what's going on, but my wifi is gone.